# O que acontece quando converto int para char?

Tags: c, conversão-de-tipo, char, cast

Um inteiro tem *4 bytes*, enquanto que um `char` tem apenas *1 byte*.

Quando eu faço essa definição:

```
int a = 1000; // 1111101000
char b = (char) a;
```

Acredito que ele vai pegar apenas 1 byte de dados, mas o que quero saber é se ele vai pegar do inicio ou do final.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considerando que um `int` são 32 bits e um `char` são 8.
Nessa conversão você pegará apenas os bits 0 até 7 do seu `int`.

Se o `int` armazenando 1000 é:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 1110 1000 // equivale a 1000 em 32 bits
^                                     ^
32                                    0
```

Convertendo para `char` você só terá:

```
1110 1000 // equivale a 232 em 8 bits
^       ^
7       0
```

Logo, o `int` que armazena 1000, quando convertido para `char`, resulta em 232.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado.

Comment: Observe que há processadores que armazenam seus dados em memória de forma diferente, portanto esta mesma operação teria resultados diverso, veja mais em http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremidade_%28ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29

Answer (score 5):

Vai pegar o byte do inicio, que na representação humana, são os dígitos menos significativos, ou seja os dígitos finais.

Digo isso pois na memória, o primeiro byte representa na verdade os dados menos significativos, e o último os mais significativos. Enquanto que nós, seres humanos, fazemos o contrário disso.

Exemplo:

```
0x12345678 <- representação humana

0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12 <- ordenação dos bytes na memória do computador x86
```

Como apontado pelo @pmg, existem arquiteturas em que esta ordem dos endereços é inversa ao colocado acima.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Disponha... é sempre bom ajudar!

Comment: Nem todos os computadores são 'little-endian' :)

Comment: @pmg: É verdade. Esse é um detalhe importante. No caso desta operação específica não deve fazer diferença.

Comment: @pmg: Você podia trazer uma daquelas respostas suas sobre isso do SOEN para cá. =D

Answer (score 3):

Referindo explicitamente o standard do C (usei o N

> ## 6 Language
>
> ## 6.3 Conversions
>
> ## 6.3.1 Arithmetic operands
>
> ## 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> <sub><sup>1</sup></sub> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> <sub><sup>2</sup></sub> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.
>
> <sub><sup>3</sup></sub> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Uma breve tradução:

1 - Se o valor puder se representado no tipo alvo, ele será.
2 - Se forem `unsigned` ocorrerá truncagem dos bits. (tal como as outras respostas dizem).
3 - Se forem `signed`, resultado é definido pela implementação.

O terceiro ponto é bastante importante. Se você for converter um `int` para um `char` pode ter resultados não esperados do seu compilador. Muito embora praticamente todos façam truncagem dos bits, você não deve assumir que isso sempre ocorre.

Prefira converter de `unsigned int` para `unsigned char` quando possível.

Answer (score -1):

O que pode acontecer na conversão de `int` para `char` é a conversão baseada na `tabela ascii`.

Por exemplo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nota: `char` nada tem haver com a tabela ascii. Apenas acontece que a maioria das implementações utilizam essa tabela para representar caracteres. E que esses caracteres são do tipo `char`. Nota2: A tabela ascii vai de 0 a 127. Os valores de 128 a 255 são parte da tabela estendidas, não sendo compatíveis com UTF-8 por exemplo.