# Por que atribuir valores maiores que 127 a um char resultam no mesmo caractere?

Tags: c, caracteres

No código abaixo eu atribuo valores maiores que 127, que seria o maior valor permitido pela tabela ASCII:

```
#include <stdio.h> int 
    main(void){
    char ch;
    ch =   65; printf( "\n %c", ch );
    ch =  321; printf( "\n %c", ch );
    ch =  577; printf( "\n %c", ch );
    ch =  833; printf( "\n %c", ch );
    ch = 1089; printf( "\n %c", ch );
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
 A
 A
 A
 A
 A
```

Por que quando o valor é maior que 128, ele continua mostrando caracteres válidos?

Answer (score 2):

O `char`, apesar do nome, é um tipo numérico. Todos os tipos numéricos têm um tamanho, e [no caso do `char`, esse tamanho é de um byte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/178483/112052).

Tendo um tamanho definido, é claro que ele terá um valor mínimo e um máximo que pode ser colocado ali. E quando você coloca um valor maior do que o máximo suportado, ocorre o *overflow*: o valor  é "truncado" para caber no espaço que aquele tipo comporta ([aqui tem uma explicação bem didática](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Epf/algoritmos/aulas/int.html)).

Você pode ver isso imprimindo o valor numérico correspondente ao `char`, assim:

```c
char ch;
ch =   65; printf("%c %d\n", ch, ch);
ch =  321; printf("%c %d\n", ch, ch);
ch =  577; printf("%c %d\n", ch, ch);
ch =  833; printf("%c %d\n", ch, ch);
ch = 1089; printf("%c %d\n", ch, ch);
```

A saída é:

```
A 65
A 65
A 65
A 65
A 65
```

Ou seja, todos os valores resultam em `65`, que ao ser convertido para caractere, resulta na letra "A".

Isso ocorre porque o valor máximo que cabe em um byte é 255 (se for `unsigned`) ou 127 (se for `signed`) - ver mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/357931/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77418/112052).

Além disso, um literal numérico (ou seja, quando você escreve `321` ou `833` diretamente no código) [acaba sendo interpretado como um `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal), e quando você atribui um `int` a um `char`, [o valor é truncado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10136/112052).

Ou seja, no fim todos os valores acabam sendo `65`.

Answer (score 1):

Porque na codificação ASCII, cada caractere é representado por 1 byte (8 bits).

Veja o que acontece com os seguintes números quando convertemos eles para binário:

```js
console.log((65).toString(2));
console.log((321).toString(2));
console.log((577).toString(2));
console.log((833).toString(2));
console.log((1089).toString(2)); // o 1090 da pergunta está errado
```

Repare que todos eles terminam com `01000001`, que são os 8 bits utilizados na conversão, o resto é ignorado. Eles correspondem a letra *A* da tabela ASCII.